# Viewpager with large number of views or dynamic views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to implement a Viewpager with a dynamic view i.e the view updates itself when user flicks/drags it left/right.The view is updated using the next row in the pre-stored database.How can i implement it?
The reason i want to do this is: I have around 3000 entries in db that i want to display one at a time.I can't create so many views at a time.

Answer (score 1):

such as bellow, hope to help you.

```
public class BottomAdatper extends PagerAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10000;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return view == o;
}

ArrayList<TextView> caches = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    caches.add((TextView) object);
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TextView tv = null;
    if (caches.size() == 0) {
        tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(60);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else {
        tv = caches.remove(0);
    }
    tv.setText("" + position);
    container.addView(tv);
    return tv;
}
}
```